# How does Autofac replace a registered service?

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

I want to write an AOP framework (in order to study)，I need to replace the service that is already registered in Autofac.

In **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection**：

```
        public static IServiceCollection BuildAopProxy(this IServiceCollection service)
        {
            if (service is null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(service));

            IServiceCollection proxyServiceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

            foreach (ServiceDescriptor item in service)
            {
                Type newType;
                Type serviceType = item.ServiceType;
                Type implementationType = item.ImplementationType;

                if (serviceType == implementationType)
                {
                    newType = DynamicProxy.CreateProxyClassType(item.ImplementationType, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    newType = DynamicProxy.CreateProxyClassType(item.ServiceType, item.ImplementationType, false);
                }
                proxyServiceCollection.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Describe(serviceType, newType, item.Lifetime));
            }
            return proxyServiceCollection;
        }
```

How does this work in Autofac? Thank you.

Comment: I'm going to get the implementationType and Override it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all about registration order. [There's a section in the documentation on it.](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#default-registrations)

Basically: **Last in wins.**

First, it's important to note that what you're using in your example is the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection library. None of that is Autofac. Autofac [can *integrate* with that](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/netcore.html), but the way you're setting up your registrations using `IServiceCollection` is not Autofac.

However, the concept **last in wins** holds for Microsoft DI as well as Autofac... and almost every other DI container.

If I register three things that implement the same interface...

```cs
svcCollection.AddTransient<IDependency, First>();
svcCollection.AddTransient<IDependency, Second>();
svcCollection.AddTransient<IDependency, Third>();
```

If you resolve `IDependency` you'll get `Third`:

```cs
var provider = svcCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
var dependency = provider.GetService<IDependency>();
// dependency.GetType() == typeof(Third)
```

If you really want to use Autofac here, you'd need to put all the registrations into Autofac using the Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Populate(svcCollection);
var container = builder.Build();

var dependency = container.Resolve<IDependency>();
// dependency.GetType() == typeof(Third)
```

Or you could switch to use native Autofac registrations directly.

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<First>().As<IDependency>();
builder.RegisterType<Second>().As<IDependency>();
builder.RegisterType<Third>().As<IDependency>();
var container = builder.Build();

var dependency = container.Resolve<IDependency>();
// dependency.GetType() == typeof(Third)
```

It appears part of what you're doing is trying to wrap some components in decorators or proxies. If you use native Autofac, there's [built in support for decorators](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html#decorators) and [type interceptors](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html) which might make your life easier. Decorators and interceptors aren't offered by the standard Microsoft DI libraries.